# Disable removing unused keys i18next-parser

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, react-i18next, react-18

I'm using `i18next-parser` for removing unused keys and generating empty keys for other languages. But now I want to disable the unused key removal feature. Because the feature is not working properly. I'm using some dynamic keys in my project. `I18next-parser` also marks those as unused. Can anyone help me with how can I disable `i18next-parser` to remove my unused keys from the JSON file?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to remove the feature altogether, you can do so by setting the value `keepRemoved: false` in your i18next-parser config file. See Options here: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-parser#options

But for dynamic keys you can also specify the values in your code in comments so the parser can detect them: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-parser#caveats